# Brush overlay rect events conflict with other elemnts events

Tags: d3.js

Imaging I create a bar chart using d3-v4.js.

Here below is the brief SVG code snippet:

```html
<svg width="400" height="300">
    <g class="brush">
        <rect class="overlay" ... ></rect>
        <rect class="selection" ... ></rect>
        <rect class="handle handle--n" ... ></rect>
        <!-- ... ...   other rect handle     ... ...  -->
    </g>
    <g class="bar">
        <rect width="200" height="20" x="0" y="0"></rect>
        <!-- ... ...   other rect bars    ... ...  -->
    </g>
</svg>
```

Considering I can interact with every rect bars (eg. "click", "mouseenter" and "mouseleave"), I make **g.bar** above of **g.brush** so that **rect.overlay** will not *overlay* above all bars.

The brush works OK only when it start from the blank area(over the **rect.overlay**). But when I brush start from the bars it is not work. Obviously, the **rect.overlay** can not capture brush events anymore.

Any solution in this situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK there is no easy way to do this. You can find one solution in [Stephan Beiskens SpeckTrackle](https://bitbucket.org/sbeisken/specktackle). It uses d3-v3 but it should work similarly with v4.

Comment: I'm trying to attatch a "mousedown" event on **g.bar** directly, if user hold and move the mouse on the bar group then draw a rect -- just mimic a brush-like behaviour. Thanks for your suggestion.